# How to call function from another .py file in python?

Tags: python, function, pycharm

I am trying to call a function 'myfunction()' defined in another py file 'file2.py' in same directory using below code

```
from file2 import *

myfunction()
```

Unfortunately, its executing my function twice. The import statement is also executing the function. Any insights on how to avoid this?

Comment: does `file2` call `myfunction` anywhere?

Comment: You can try using as word like this 
`from file2 import myfunction as myfunc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are calling inside your `file2.py` your function `myfunction()`

when you do

```
from file2 import *
```

you are loading every definitions (class, def, etc), and of course, every function called inside that .py.

To avoid this problem you can call your function myfunction() in your file2.py inside this scope:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myfunction()
```

in this way it will not be executed when imported, but only if the file2.py is executed directly:

```
python3 file2.py
```

Comment: Thank you!.. Exactly this was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
#File name = file2
class file3:
   def method():
      print ("printing statement")
      return "Hello world"
```

Main file name **file1.py**

```
from file2 import *
print(file3.method())
```

You can define function and write return statement to avoid extra printing

Answer (score 0):

Check your `file2` and look for anything with `myfunction()` in it. If there is something like it, just remove it.